# Zend AutoLoader not functioning properly under Shared hosting

Tags: zend-framework, deployment, shared-hosting

I recently lauched a zend framework project on a shared hosting. With much struggle, I got the first index page working, but pass it all the autoloadable classes like models, forms, mappers are not found.

Here is the version of .htaccess i am using outside the public directory on the root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

A bit surprising fact is that same mappers and forms are recognised in the front page, or the baseURL, but surpass it, nothing is working.

What am i doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Your .htaccess looks weird but I don't think that's the cause. Is Zend Framework on the php inlude path?

Comment: can you show your include path? can you show us the exception thrown when the autoloader fails also?

Comment: Can you show your code? It should work, and the autoloader generally has nothing to do with rewrite rules. But it's hard to tell without some kind of error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you copy `index.php` and `.htaccess` from the Zend Framework "public" folder and put it in your `public_html` or equivalent directory.  If your Zend Framework application directory is in the same directory as public_html then the default .htaccess file and index.php file should work.

```
/home/yoursite
--application/
---- controllers
---- forms/
---- models/
---- views/
-- library/
-- public_html/ (public)
---- .htaccess
---- index.php
```

Comment: still, the classes are not found and file paths are not working.

Comment: Can you post what your index.php file looks like, and also you would need to use the stock .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Basic idea is if a file exist for requested url on server then send it to the client browser otherwise forward the request to  ZF application to deal with it.

To make your public dir accessible under root domain edit Apache httpd.conf file instead . Map your virtual host to public dir directly .

Comment: I guess, you are unaware of the fact that I am asking about deploying in a shared hosting environment. This is the default .htaccess that ships with zend frameword.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the solution that i looked for and apply. It's worked for me.
http://blog.motane.lu/2009/11/24/zend-framework-and-web-hosting-services/

You fill all content of /public_html/.htaccess (not /public_html/public/.htaccess) by

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```